# Firebase init not working on windows

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

Project selection during firebase init is not working. I tried upgrading NodeJS and npm and still got issues. The Arrow keys do not move up and down in the project list as expected and so you are not able to choose an app and so create a firebase.json. Note: I am using git bash and have also tried cygwin

Answer (score 2):

For future references, this is the problem with Git Bash. I stumbled upon while trying to run `eslint --init`. So you have a bunch of choices and it specifically says to `Use arrow keys` and they seem not be working. 
But they are working, the place where `>` points is the option currently selected. Now if you press the up or down arrow key, this symbol `>` **doesn't move**, and the cursor may or may not move depending on the screen space, but the option which is currently selected is changed depending upon how many times you pressed the up/down key.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out a workaround although not ideal you can init the firebase project in windows command shell and then switch back to git bash